# Bizarre behavior using NSolve and ParametricPlot3D

Tags: equation-solving, graphics3d, numerics

Thanks to help I received here a few days ago I am using this command to numerically solve a system of three implicit functions:

```
de[t_] := {x, y, z} /. 
   NSolve[f[x, t] && g[y, t] && h[z, t], {x, y, z}, Reals];
```

and then

```
ParametricPlot3D[de[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
 PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[2]]
```

f, g, and h are rather complicated, involving Sin and Cos [See below].  The above works pretty well.  However, due to the complex nature of f, g, and h, the 3D plot includes spurious curves [image link below].  I should be able to eliminate that flaw by adding a condition r:

```
de[t_] := {x, y, z} /. 
   NSolve[f[x, t] && g[y, t] && h[z, t] && Abs[r[x,y,z]] < eps, {x, y, z}, Reals];
```

for small eps.  r[x,y,z] is a polynomial of degree 4.  However, no matter what I do, the addition of the Abs[...] condition kills the entire graph!  Even if I set eps to a ridiculously large value like 10000000000 the graph is destroyed.  Yet if I replace Abs[..] with a simple linear expression like x + y, then the original (flawed) graph reappears.  But if I use x^2 + y, it disappears again!  I find this utterly bizarre.

The equations are here: https://pastebin.com/QqmqhFXB

The Mathematica graph that I get is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7py0i.jpg

Comment: It's hard to say anything helpful if you can't provide an example other people can evaluate. Maybe try to come up with a simpler example that has the same issue?

Comment: I just tried to paste the example but I get the error message, "too many characters."  How can I upload the example?  I suppose I could do three comments.

Comment: Can you try putting it in [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com), and then linking to it here in your question?

Comment: OK, here is the link to pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/QqmqhFXB

Comment: Here is the plot produced by mathematica.  This is quite reasonable, except that only one of the curves is correct.

https://imgur.com/uxPQYyW

Comment: Please edit your question to include this additional info, instead of leaving them in comments.

Comment: OK I edited the original post.

Comment: I have no problems with `r[x_, y_] := x^2 + y` at all.

Comment: Taiki:  What do you mean "no problem"?  I restarted Mathematica.  When I use r[x_, y_] := x^2 + y with condition r[x,y] < eps,  I get no graph at all -- empty white space.  When I use r[x_, y_] := x + y, r[x,y] < eps, I get the graph with two curves close to each other, as in the image I linked to above.  Here eps = 10^18.